# Avoid getting whole figure caption text into figure list in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

When I create a figure caption with the below method, the whole figure caption is included in the figure list, which is annoying as some figures have a lot in the caption. The figure list is created automatically by bookdown. Is there a way of separating this into something like "figure title" and "figure text", where only the figure title is included in the list?

````
```{r, fig.cap="\\label{fig:figureOne}Figure caption goes here. This caption is sort of long, but is informative for the figure", echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.align='center'}
knitr::include_graphics("images/figure1.png")
```
````

This looks like this in the knitted pdf:
[image: test]
***Figure 1.1: Figure caption goes here. This caption is sort of long, but is informative for the figure***

List of figures then looks like this:

```
1.1 Figure caption goes here. This caption is sort of long, but is informative for the figure
```

Is it possible to make it look like this instead:

```
1.1 Figure caption goes here.
```

I couldn't find any documentation on subcaptions or figure text other than figure captions.

Comment: There are ways but I have to wonder: If you don’t want to include the text then why not just leave it out?

Comment: I need to have text on the figures for explanation, but I don't want the full text in the figure list, kind of just the name of the figure, not the explanation

Comment: I understood that. So just add the name, not the explanation, in the RMarkdown code.

Comment: How would I then add other text to the figure, if not in the caption?

Comment: @KonradRudolph the figure list is automatically generated since I use bookdown, so I can't manually change what is used as the figure name

Comment: I like to take charge of the construction of short (for table of figures) and long figure captions, as shown in examples using the `putHcap` function [here](http://hbiostat.org/R/Hmisc/examples.html).

Comment: The solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69094228/give-a-single-figure-multiple-captions-in-rmarkdown-pdf-book-output) should help with this.